# Exporting nested JSON output to CSV file

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

I am trying to find a way to export nested JSON data into columns in a CSV file.

This is the JSON output for one of the checks we have in the 3rd party solution.

```json
{
        "url": "***",
        "id": 46092,
        "guid": "a200efc4-2b05-422a-8785-ca5868aa7c1d",
        "name": "***",
        "check_type": "FprXnet",
        "check_type_name": "Real Browser, Chrome",
        "check_type_api": "browser",
        "enabled": true,
        "location": "Finland, Helsinki",
        "country_code": "FI",
        "sla_percent_current_month": 99.44116132753345,
        "timestamp_utc": "2023-07-31T13:45:03.563",
        "severity": "I",
        "value": 37106,
        "unit": "ms",
        "target_sla": null,
        "check_symbol": "N7_M13522_C46092_FPR_20190619_141926_713",
        "threshold_w": null,
        "threshold_w_dynamic": null,
        "threshold_e": null,
        "threshold_e_dynamic": null,
        "threshold_lo_w": null,
        "threshold_lo_w_dynamic": null,
        "threshold_lo_e": null,
        "threshold_lo_e_dynamic": null,
        "scheduled_inclusion": null,
        "scheduled_exclusion": "mon-sun : 01:00-01:15;",
        "interval_seconds": 600,
        "last_result_details": {
            "message": "10 steps, 10 pages, 296 urls, 185350/46334226 sent/received bytes",
            "attempts": 1,
            "result_code": 0
        },
        "tags": {
            "24/7 procedure": [
                "24/7"
            ],
            "Country": [
                "Finland"
            ],
            "Environment": [
                "Prod"
            ],
            "ITSystemCode": [
                "***"
            ]
        }
    },
```

This is how the CSV is being exported:

[image: Exported CSV file example]

What I need to do is to add additional columns:

> ("24/7 procedure", "Country", "Environment" and "ITSystemCode")

In a CSV file for the following nested information.

```json
"tags": {
            "24/7 procedure": [
                "24/7"
            ],
            "Country": [
                "Finland"
            ],
            "Environment": [
                "Prod"
            ],
            "ITSystemCode": [
                "***"
            ]
        }
```

This is the current script I got so far:

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://***.***.com/v3/checks?enabled=true&auth_ticket=***' -Method 'GET'

$date = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy-HH-mm"

$response | Select-Object -Property name,location,id,tags,timestamp_utc | Export-Csv -Path "Checks_$date.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";"
```

I am trying to export the CSV file so it includes the columns as follows:

> name,location,id,tags("24/7 procedure", "Country", "Environment", "ITSystemCode"),timestamp_utc

Tried to follow this, but I couldn't get it to work/don't really understand this as I am transitioning from Python to PowerShell at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be close to what you're looking for, basically you create an array of the selectable properties and within in you include [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.3) for the nested properties in `.tags`:

```
$properties = @(
    'name'
    'location'
    'id'
    @{ N = '24/7 procedure'; E = { $_.tags.'24/7 procedure' } }
    @{ N = 'Country'; E = { $_.tags.Country } }
    @{ N = 'Environment'; E = { $_.tags.Environment } }
    @{ N = 'ITSystemCode'; E = { $_.tags.ITSystemCode } }
    'timestamp_utc'
)

$date = Get-Date -Format 'MM-dd-yyyy-HH-mm'
$response | Select-Object $properties |
    Export-Csv "Checks_$date.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ';'
```

The resulting Csv for this example would look like:

```
"name";"location";"id";"24/7 procedure";"Country";"Environment";"ITSystemCode";"timestamp_utc"
"***";"Finland, Helsinki";"46092";"24/7";"Finland";"Prod";"***";"7/31/2023 1:45:03 PM"
```

If the `Select-Object` statement with *calculated properties* is too confusing for you, you might find it easier by just creating a new object output of your `$response`, for this see **[Everything you wanted to know about PSCustomObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.3)**.

```bash
$response | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        'name'           = $_.name
        'location'       = $_.location
        'id'             = $_.id
        '24/7 procedure' = $_.tags.'24/7 procedure' 
        'Country'        = $_.tags.Country
        'Environment'    = $_.tags.Environment
        'ITSystemCode'   = $_.tags.ITSystemCode
        'timestamp_utc'  = $_.timestamp_utc
    }
} | Export-Csv "Checks_$date.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ';'
```

Comment: Beautiful, just tested. Thanks a lot for helping out here Santiago. I see now how can I use properties.

Comment: @KristapsKozlovskis I added a different way of accomplishing the exact same thing that might give you an easier time reading ;)

Comment: Thanks Santiago. Much appreciated for the effort. Took notes for both and will do research the links today. :)